# How to generate one time password when creating user and send the same to users mail id in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send a random one-time password to the user when I create a new user and make him change the password when the user login for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest different approach to this.

When you create a user, set the active flag to false. so the account is not active and then cannot log in.

No need to generate a password, leave it blank.

Instead, create a url with special token and send the url. If the user goes to this url, it will present a form to set the password for this user.

This link is only one time use, and it can even expire after certain number of days.

You can look at `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` in `django.contrib.auth.tokens` to see how to generate such tokens and change it accordingly.

You will also need to craft the url to include somehow which user to use ( probably obscure it somehow as it is not apparent ).

Comment: Could you clarify how to generate this URL? I've managed to create the token but I'm not sure what steps to take from that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is simple solution for that. First of all let me describe user model with minimal requirements for the task:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# ... other import

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
  has_set_password = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  # ... other fields
```

On the other hand, If you do not want to pollute model with unnecessary fields, check out the value of the `last_login` field, which comes from the `AbstractUser` model and it's value should be None, if user has not logged in yet.

After the part above, I'd define [post save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) method for the CustomUser model or in the view where user is created - I'd just assign random one-time password. After user signs in, I would check the `has_set_password` flag, if it is `False` redirect them to set new password (or do something else), if it is `True` just sign in.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. I Have tried it for Custom User Creation.
You can first generate a random password/pin like

```
from random import SystemRandom    

def user_create(username):
    new_random_obj = SystemRandom()
    #generate: 6 digits pin
    pin = new_random_obj.randrange(100000, 999999)

    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=pin)
```

Then your create_user Method In UserManager may look Like

```
 def create_user(self, username, password=None, location=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have an username')

        user = self.model(
            username=username
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```